# Does inline have any effect when using const function attribute?

Tags: c, gcc, g++, clang

Take this function

```
__attribute_const__ static inline int mul(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

versus this one

```
__attribute_const__ static int mul(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

Is there a reason to use inline when using a const attribute? Does it help the compiler at all to use inline here?

Comment: They seem orthogonal to me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The inline functions are substituted where they are called (at compilation time) and the attribute const is telling the compiler that further calls to the function using the same parameters could be avoided, because the result will be the same. If you are marking the const function as inline then you are loosing the const behavior since the inline is not per se a "call" and the const optimization relays on repeated calls

Comment: The `inline` attribute changes the linkage of the function. It doesn't cause the compiler to substitute the function where it's called (only serrves as a hint that is usually ignored). Even if the compiler does substitute the function call, this does not conflict with attribute(const) functions because the compiler can just avoid substituing the function call on the second call, just like it could avoid making the function call.

Answer (score 1):

None of the attributes necessarily help here, because a `static` function would be inlined anyway regardless of `inline` if the compiler so decides, and because it is a `static` function then the source would be present in the translation unit where it would be used, then the compiler can also see that it calculates the product of the two arguments and compilers are smart enough to conclude that the product of two arguments depends only the values of those arguments.

The `inline` case gets more interesting in the case of *`inline`/`extern inline`*. Also, the attribute case gets more interesting when the compiler *cannot* see the code (because the function is defined only in another translation unit), or cannot deduce its behaviour properly - for example a const function might touch some common lookup tables initialized in the beginning of the program but the compiler wouldn't be able to ensure that they will remain constant.